# PHP embed shared library not loading any extentions

Tags: php, c

I have a similar proplem to https://serverfault.com/questions/702661/php5-embed-does-not-load-extensions?rq=1. Not sure if he's writing a shared library using embed. But my problem is when "running" my built shared library. As an executable loads the extensions. But not as a shared library (.so). All my extensions fail. All of them are in the location specified.

```
Failed loading /usr/lib/php5/20121212/opcache.so:  /usr/lib/php5/20121212/opcache.so: undefined symbol: zend_ini_boolean_displayer_cb
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/oci8.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/oci8.so: undefined symbol: OnUpdateLong in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo.so: undefined symbol: compiler_globals in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_oci.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_oci.so: undefined symbol: php_info_print_table_start in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo.so: undefined symbol: compiler_globals in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_oci.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/pdo_oci.so: undefined symbol: php_info_print_table_start in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/oci8.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/oci8.so: undefined symbol: OnUpdateLong in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/curl.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/json.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/json.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20121212/readline.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20121212/readline.so: undefined symbol: OnUpdateString in Unknown on line 0
```

By the sound of the "undefined symbol" warning it's obviously missing something environment related. A Zend library or something not loaded to handle loading extensions.

The code below is exactly what I use in the .so file, except obviously main is renamed. I'm guessing somewhere, for the .so, an environment setup needs to happen:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "/usr/include/php/sapi/embed/php_embed.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{       
    char *filename = "/path/to/php/test.php";
    argc--;
    argv++;

    PHP_EMBED_START_BLOCK(argc,argv)

        zval zoutput;
        char *include_file;     

        spprintf( &include_file, 0, "include '%s';", filename  );
        zend_eval_string( include_file, &zoutput, filename TSRMLS_CC );
        efree(include_file);

    PHP_EMBED_END_BLOCK()

    return 0;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.